# No valid RoutedEventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle">
            <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="status_SelectionChanged"/>
</Style>
```

`status_SelectionChanged` method:

```
public void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
```

> Error: not valid System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your method signature for SelectionChanged should use `RoutedEventArgs e` instead of `SelectionChangedEventArgs e`

[Here is the MSDN showing the RoutedEventHandler signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

see [ListBoxItem.Selected](http://ListBoxItem.Selected)